# Как загрузить docker image?

Tags: docker

Выполняю команду

> docker images

получаю список образов в системе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь выполняю команду

docker save infosyswebapi:dev > infosys_docker_img

На жестком диске появляется файл infosys_docker_img

Теперь удаляю образ из системы командой

docker rmi infosyswebapi:dev

Образ исчез из списка образов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне теперь загрузить обратно в систему образ из файла infosys_docker_img, который ранее я сохранил на жестком диске?

Answer (score 1):

Это делается вот так:

```
#docker load < infosys_docker_img
```

просто оказался битый infosys_docker_img. Заново пересохранил и заработало